# Two PC in one 'secured' network. Detect ports to communicate between them

Tags: networking, firewall

Have two PC in one tricky network (can ping each other). But the network is overkilled with complicated security things (proxy, firewalls, network group settings, etc). Have a share folder where both pc have access (smb allowed?).
But for custom communication - I need a direct connection between those computes using direct TCP connection on any port(s).

What is the best way to check what ports I can use ? 
The first idea would be to open a lot of ports on pc1 and scan it with nmap or something like this. 
What port ranges are better to use ?

Comment: You would ask the network administrator/person that set up the security.  They obviously know what they are doing, and are most likely running an IDS to stop what you are attempting anyway.